# Using mergJSON in a LiveCode Standalone - no functionality?

Tags: json, livecode

I'm using the mergJSON external in LiveCode and all is working fine in the IDE but not in the standalone application.
I use LiveCode 6.0.1 Community Edition for Mac OSX 10.8.3 with mergJSON (https://github.com/montegoulding/mergJSON)

When I create a **standalone application (Mac)** the mergJSON functionality doesn't seem to exist any more.  There are no errors messages, simply that nothing works.

I have a button that grabs a piece of JSON data, converts it into a LiveCode array and populates a DataGrid. This works fine in the IDE. It does nothing when I press it in the standalone application.

**Stand alone generator settings**

```
  LiveCode > Standalone Settings > Select Inclusions
```

should make sure that for the standalone application the mergJSON script libraries are visible, which they are.  Currently I'm using "*Search for required inclusions when saving the standalone...*" option the Standalone Settings.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed this tutorial on setting up the user extensions folder for a third party extension. Note that the standalone builder will show an external if it's in the Externals folder but look for it in the Runtime folder so you need to add it there too.

http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/6347-how-to-install-3rd-party-externals-for-use-in-the-ide-and-standalone-builder

Also note that there's no Universal or PowerPC build so you need to build your app for x86 only.